# c# Stack overflow error with recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, stack-overflow

I do a complete list of folders on the server, but about 65,000 StackOverFlowException share, there is an exception. how to get around

```
static List<string> FolderList = new List<string>();
static void Selection(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
    FolderList.Add(dir.FullName);
    foreach (var a_dir in dir.GetDirectories())
    {
        Selection(a_dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: (I've fixed it for you on this occasion.)

Comment: Step through the code using the debugger. It's a lot faster and more informative than asking strangers what's wrong with the code.

Comment: How about using an [overload of GetDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms143325(v=vs.110).aspx) that does the "hard work" for you?

Comment: English version of Christian's link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143325(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to use recursion when you have unknown depth. Alternatively, you can use the overload for GetDirectories (which uses a Stack data structure and not recursion):

```
static List<string> FolderList = new List<string>();
static void Selection(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
    var dirs = dir.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (var a_dir in dirs)
    {
        FolderList.Add(dir.FullName);
    }
}
```

If you still encounter an exception, you need to change your logic to a traditional while loop.

Docs below for `GetDirectories`:

> searchPattern:
>
> The search string to match against the names of
> directories. This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal
> path and wildcard (* and ?) characters (see Remarks), but doesn't
> support regular expressions. The default pattern is "*", which returns
> all files.
>
> searchOption:
>
> One of the enumeration values that specifies whether the search operation > should include only the current directory or all subdirectories

Comment: Is this recursive (i.e returns all sub folders within sub folders)?

Comment: @YosiDahari I checked the implementation, it uses a stack internally and not a recursive function.

Comment: @YosiDahari means to ask that does the method return *all* folders, including folders within folders within folders and so on?

Comment: @EvilTak as the docs states above *include all subdirectories*